# node.js: Async.parallel, callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I want to get the amount of viewers from each subforum. I wanted to do this by using async.parallel and then receiving the results at the end. The problem is that I want to call the same function 4 times (one time for each subforum) with a different argument. How do I do this? The way you see it below is how I tried to do it, but it gave me an error that 'callback is not a function'. Does anyone know how to properly do this?

**Node.js code**

```
router.get('/getSubViews', function(req, res) {

async.parallel([
    getViewers('quests'),
    getViewers('tips & tricks'),
    getViewers('general'),
    getViewers('cities')
], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Something went wrong",
            err: err
        });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Successfully retrieved the section",
        obj: 'whatever'
    });
});

function getViewers(subForum, callback){

        SubViewCount.findOne({'section': subForum}, function(err, doc){
            callback(null, doc.views);
        })
    }
```

Comment: You're calling `getViewers()` with one argument, which means inside, `callback` isn't a function. Try replacing your function content with `return SubViewCount.findOne({'section': subForum});` I'd also look into bluebird's Promise.all()

Comment: {"Backend returned code: ": 500, "body was: ": "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta char…\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"}

Comment: It caused an error.

Comment: `async.parallel` seems to be an early attempt to handle Promises. While you can probably get it to work somehow, my recommendation would be to make use of the fact that `.findOne()` returns a Promise. Use this: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: ok, I'll have a look